# Bazel reload times very slow using Angular

Tags: angular, bazel, bazel-rules-nodejs

Running an Angular project with 20+ separate modules and the reload times after making any simple change are 10s+ for each module. Using incremental builds so only effected modules are rebuilt, but the times are a bottleneck to development. Any insight in where to start debugging the issue or a fix is appreciated.

Using build_bazel_rules_nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run with profiling enabled,during the loading phase to see what's going on? You can run with --nobuild --noanalyze to avoid doing the whole build. As mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/g/bazel-discuss/c/qizKwL2pxSA/m/ztjstuPtFwAJ) to see the performance